# Trying to create a Dice HUD on Second Life that pulls information for different rolls from a notecard

Tags: linden-scripting-language

So I'm working on something that's going to be a rather large undertaking. I've figured out how to do a "bare-bones" kind of dice hud that just rolls a basic 2-20. However now I need to go to the next step.

I want to make a roleplaying system dice hud for my sim. For this I want it so that when you click the HUD you get a menu, that lists all the skills in my system. When you click the skill it refrences a notecard in the Hud to do some minor math before displaying the result: IE.

There's a normal 2d6, 2d8, 2d10, 2d12, 2d16, 2d20 ((Whatever basic configuration that always rolls a standard die))

Though I want it to look into a note card to add in a character's "STATS" and "SKILL LEVEL"

So say they want to hit someone with a sword?

I want the Hud to generate a random value between 2 and 12, then add in the character's Strength, speed, perception stats as well as their sword skill level.

If I could see the basics of HOW to start this I can then move forward from there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write into a note card using a LSL (or other) script.

If you want to roll a dice, simply use llRound( llFrand ); or integer x = (integer)llFrand(19)+1;

You could use a webserver to save information like that. Just google free web space, you're gonna find a lot. SL's HTTP communication is, let's say, ok.

This is kind of a big project. If you don't know where/how to start you should hire a professional. Just look for groups in-world. You're going to find a lot of people willing to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In LSL you cannot write in a notecard, however if you try OpenSim you can use that function:

```
osMakeNotecard(string notecardName, list contents);
```

But that is only available in OpenSim, see [osMakeNotecard](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/OsMakeNotecard).